I keep getting the Dooo app stopped error
I am constantly getting a "stopped" error in the Dooo application. After the application stops, when I request an error report, it shows the following complex code.
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method int java.lang.String.hashCode() on a null object reference
 at com.dizinow.now.fragment.HomeFragment.onCreateView(HomeFragment.java:351)
 at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2963)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:518)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:282)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2189)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2100)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2002)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3138)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:3072)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:251)
 at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:502)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1456)
 at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:8195)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3796)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
 at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2291)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
 at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:210)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:299)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8319)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:556)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1038)

In the code where the error occurs, the following photo shows it. How can I fix this? I would be very grateful if you could help. If it's a long explanation. Thank you.
PHOTO
The application was supposed to work, the interface was supposed to open.

Please read Unfortunately MyApp has stopped. How can I solve this? and Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.

Please do not share your contact details on [SO].
